# Insert formulas with variable VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, xlookup

I have the following code and I am getting "identifier under cursor not recognized" on all portions within the For loop.

```
Sub Finalize_Macro()
'
' Finalize all data on the Offer Data worksheet
'


Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ValCol As Long
Dim DayCol As Long
Dim i As Integer

Set DSheet = Worksheets("Offer Data")
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ValCol = PSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1 
DayCol = PSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 


DSheet.Select
[E1:I1] = [{"Redemption Value", "Redemption Days", "Theo", "Actual", "Rated Days"}]

For i = 2 To LastRow
    Cells(i, 5).Formula = "=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(A" & i & ",PivotTable!(A:A),PivotTable!.Columns(" & ValCol & ")),0)"
    Cells(i, 6).Formula = "=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(A" & i & ",PivotTable!(A:A),PivotTable!.Columns(" & DayCol & ")),0)"
    Cells(i, 7).Formula = "=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(A" & i & ",'Big Query Data'!(B:B),'Big Query Data'!(C:C)),0)"
    Cells(i, 8).Formula = "=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(A" & i & ",'Big Query Data'!(B:B),'Big Query Data'!(D:D)),0)"
    Cells(i, 9).Formula = "=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(A" & i & ",'Big Query Data'!(B:B),'Big Query Data'!(E:E)),0)"
Next
                        
                        
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

If anyone could help advise why this isn't working, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: ValCol and DayCol need to be: `PSheet.Column(ValCol).Address` in the formula.

Comment: `.Formula` needs to be `.Formula2`, and you don't need a loop to insert a formula.

Comment: The parens around column letters should be removed. `'Big Query Data'!B:B`

Comment: Get rid of the `.Columns` in the first two formulas after following Scott's suggestion.

Comment: @ScottCraner - When changing those in the formula (and also including BigBen's suggestions) I get a compile error: "Method or data member not found" on the .column portion

Comment: That should be `.Columns`.

Comment: @BigBen I was using a loop because this formula is being used down a sheet with a dynamic # of rows- I initially tried using "range" to input these formulas but using a loop seemed easier. Is there a better way I should be inputting these?

Comment: With a one-liner... e.g. `Range("E2:E" & LastRow).Formula2 = "=IFERROR(....)`.

Comment: @BigBen thank you so much! I had that before but I switched to a loop when I wasn't able to get it to work (thinking, for some reason, that the "range" portion was my problem).

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up using - thanks to ScottCraner & BigBen for the assistance!

```
    Sub Finalize_Macro()
'
' Finalize all data on the Offer Data worksheet
'


Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ValCol As Long
Dim DayCol As Long
Dim i As Integer

Set DSheet = Worksheets("Offer Data")
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ValCol = PSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1 
DayCol = PSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 


DSheet.Select
[E1:I1] = [{"Redemption Value", "Redemption Days", "Theo", "Actual", "Rated Days"}]

    Range("E2:E" & LastRow).Formula2 = "=IFERROR(XLOOKUP($A2,PivotTable!$A:$A,PivotTable!" & PSheet.Columns(ValCol).Address & "),0)"
    Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Formula2 = "=IFERROR(XLOOKUP($A2,PivotTable!$A:$A,PivotTable!" & PSheet.Columns(ValCol).Address & "),0)"
    Range("G2:G" & LastRow).Formula2 = "=IFERROR(XLOOKUP($A2,'Big Query Data'!$B:$B,'Big Query Data'!$C:$C),0)"
    Range("H2:H" & LastRow).Formula2 = "=IFERROR(XLOOKUP($A2,'Big Query Data'!$B:$B,'Big Query Data'!$D:$D),0)"
    Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Formula2 = "=IFERROR(XLOOKUP($A2,'Big Query Data'!$B:$B,'Big Query Data'!$E:$E),0)"
    
                        
                        
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```